# Automating mobile browser with Selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, appium, mobile-browser

Can we automate chrome browser on mobile with Selenium.
 Without using the Appium.
  That is I need to automate browser on mobile without using appium but selenium.. So Is there a way to do same in JAVA..

Comment: What's the reason to not use Appium to drive the mobile device?

Comment: Sir Breaks.. Its actually a scenario which requires no server to be launched to automate mobile browser.....

Answer (score -1):

Download jar for Android driver here:
https://github.com/selendroid/selendroid

Start is up from command line:

```
$ java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.17.0-with-dependencies.jar
```

In your test, instantiate the driver like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.ANDROID)
```

Answer (score -1):

just instal Appium and use desired capabilities, these here are a setup for emulator with pre-set emulator call "Android", managed in Android Studio, AVD Manager.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException{
    DesiredCapabilities  capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("device","Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", "Chrome");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "4.3");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "WINDOWS");
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
}
```

or if this doesn't work try this bellow:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities=new DesiredCapabilities();//DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    ChromeOptions options=new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOptions("androidPackage", "com.android.chrome");
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

I'm using latest dependancies of appium server and appium-java-client